# How to ouput SymPy solution as LaTex

Tags: python, latex, sympy, jupyter-lab

Does anyone know an easy way to have SymPy display the solution with a LaTex format? The solution is going into a report, and I do not want to have to retype the whole thing. The equations are displayed nice, but not the solution.
Here is my code:

```
L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5=smp.symbols('L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5')
def position_vectors():
    R1=np.array([L1*smp.cos(theta1),L1*smp.sin(theta1)])
    R2=np.array([L2*smp.cos(theta2),L2*smp.sin(theta2)])
    R3=np.array([L3*smp.cos(theta3),L3*smp.sin(theta3)])
    R4=np.array([L4*smp.cos(theta4),L4*smp.sin(theta4)])
    R5=np.array([L5*smp.cos(theta5),L5*smp.sin(theta5)])
    return smp.Matrix([R1,R2,R3,R4,R5])
R=position_vectors()
display(R)

i_comps=smp.Eq(R[1,0]+R[2,0]+R[3,0]-R[0,0]-R[4,0],0)
j_comps=smp.Eq(R[1,1]+R[2,1]+R[3,1]-R[0,1]-R[4,1],0)

theta2_solutions=smp.solve([i_comps,j_comps],theta2)
theta5_solutions=smp.solve([i_comps,j_comps],theta5)

display(theta2_solutions)
display(theta5_solutions)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[(pi - asin((L1*sin(theta1) - L3*sin(theta3) - L4*sin(theta4) + L5*sin(theta5))/L2),),
 (asin((L1*sin(theta1) - L3*sin(theta3) - L4*sin(theta4) + L5*sin(theta5))/L2),)]
[(pi - asin((-L1*sin(theta1) + L2*sin(theta2) + L3*sin(theta3) + L4*sin(theta4))/L5),),
 (asin((-L1*sin(theta1) + L2*sin(theta2) + L3*sin(theta3) + L4*sin(theta4))/L5),)]
```

I tried using the smp.Latex() function but it did not render in a markdown cell. I think there is something off with the LaTex code, but I am relatively new to the LaTex language so I am stuck.

Comment: There is a different SO site for latex. I suggest you to post there. Here is the link https://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Running this should enable the full latex printer to do its work.

```py
import sympy as smp
smp.init_printing()
```

If this doesn't work, try `smp.init_printing(use_latex=True)`.

Comment: This worked great, thank you.